# Applying a function to polygons of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile

I am new to working with Spatial Data in R, and I'm having trouble accessing the polygons and relating the polygons to the data. Here's the thing:

I have `municipalities` a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, and I can access the data section with `municipalities@data` this of course is a data frame and I can do the usual manipulation with `sapply` and similar functions. I want, however, to create a new variable in data that depends on the polygons. So for example, I would like to do:

`municipalities$pointInPolygon <- sapply(POLYGON, function(x){getPointInPolygon{x})`

or something similar. Thing is, I still don't understand how the data and polygon sections of my SPDF are related and how to access the later.

Any answers,tips, or resources to understand `SpatialPolygonsDataFrames` better is appreciated.

PS: [Here](https://www.efrainmaps.es/app/download/5495763459/M%C3%A9xico_Estados.rar?t=1422619455) is the data I'm using and how I am reading it

```
municipalities <- rgdal::readOGR("México_Estados/México_Estados.shp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `sf` package for `simple features`:

```r
municipalities_sf <- sf::read_sf("México_Estados.shp")
class(municipalities_sf)
#
> [1] "sf"         "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
#
```

Then you can use `dplyr`, `purrr`, etc on data frame directly:

```r
municipalities_sf |>
  dplyr::mutate(purrr::map(geometry, function(x){myFantasticFunction}))
```